# Proving functional space $B(A)$ as Banach space.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I have a functional space as below.
Let A be a non empty space and
$$ B(A) := \{ f : A \rightarrow \mathbb {R}  \lvert \, \lVert f \rVert_\infty  : = \sup_{a \in A} \, \lvert f(a) \rvert < \infty \}  $$

I prove like this
Let $x_n $ be a cauchy sequence in $ B(A)$. The for $ \epsilon >0 \,, \exists N \in \mathbb N , \forall \, m,r  $
$$ \lVert f_{m} - f_r \rVert < \epsilon $$
$$ \sup_{a \in A} \, \lvert f^{(m)}(a) -f^{(r)}(a) \rvert  < \epsilon $$
$$  \lvert f^{(m)}(a) -f^{(r)}(a) \rvert  < \epsilon  \, \forall a \in A $$
This is a cauchy sequence in $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb R$ is complete space. The sequence converges for every  $a\in A$. Therefore lets define $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that  as $ m \rightarrow \infty \implies f^m (a) \rightarrow f(a) \implies f(a) \in B(A)$
Then from
$$ \lVert f_{m} - f_r \rVert < \epsilon $$
we have as  $ r \rightarrow \infty $
$$ \lVert f_{m} - f \rVert < \epsilon $$
$$ \sup_{a \in A} \, \lvert f^{(m)}(a) -f(a) \rvert  < \epsilon $$
$$  \lvert f^{(m)}(a) -f(a) \rvert  < \epsilon \, \forall a \in A $$
Therefore $B(A)$ is compelte space . Hence it is banach space. Is this proof correct or there are some flaws.

Comment: $f(a)$ is a real value, how can $f(a)\in B(A)$, maybe you mean $f\in B(A)$. You have to prove $\|f\|_\infty<\infty$

Comment: Seems ok to me. Just add at the end 
$$|f(a)| \le |f(a) - f^m(a)| + |f^m(a)|$$
and take the sup on $A$ to show that $f \in B(A)$.

Comment: Thanks, @Alessandro ,for clearing

Comment: Thanks @Falcon for additonal comment